# How to align two column in a three column table

Tags: html, css

i am facing problem in adjustment of last row. i want last row containing two `td` of equal size.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th >Monthly Savings</th><th>Monthly Savings</th><th>Monthly Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>January</td>
        <td>$100</td><td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">February</td>
        <td colspan="2">$80</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I assume you are aware that your table has 3 columns. Thus, the alst `<tr>` makes no sense.  So either you define your table so as to allow for 4 columns, or you simply create a new table with two columns.  
Please be aware that plain HTML is not very reliable when it comes to defining a fixed layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**remove** the `colspan` in this `td`
`<td colspan="2">February</td>` into this `<td>February</td>`

```css
table, td{border:solid 1px red;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <th >Monthly Savings</th><th>Monthly Savings</th><th>Monthly Savings</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td><td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td >February</td>
    <td colspan="2">$80</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

**[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/646096ze/2/)**

Comment: Rohit i want to give 50% of width to both tds of tr

Comment: @AyushSrivastava i thing you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/646096ze/2/

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Monthly Savings</th>
    <th>Monthly Savings</th>
    <th>Monthly Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td colspan="2">$80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is this what you are expecting ?